# SVN could not open requested filesystem

Tags: svn, configuration, apache2, file-permissions, configuration-files

I am facing a problem in accessing svn repository via http. My apache2 configuration file settings have:

```
<Location /svn>
     DAV svn
     SVNParentPath /home/ubuntu/svn
     SVNListParentPath On
     AuthType Basic
     AuthName "m.jacando.com"
     AuthUserFile /etc/subversion/passwd
     Require valid-user
</Location>
```

And after the successful authentication. I am getting an error message.

```
svn: E000002: Could not open the requested SVN filesystem
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Note:[For setting-up new repos, i followed](http://help.ubuntu.com/community/Subversion) https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Subversion
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Drop the trailing / from the SVNParentPath, so that it looks like this

```
SVNParentPath /home/ubuntu/svn
```

Comment: Still the same error. I even tried changing SVNParentPath to SVNPath as well. But none of them seems to be working.